# Accessing Rust from RStudio terminal

Tags: r, docker, rust, rstudio

This is the Dockerfile I created to install Rust within RStudio in the Rocker project maintained by Carl Boettiger and Dirk Eddelbuettel:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget
ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/usr/local/rustup \
    CARGO_HOME=/usr/local/cargo

RUN set -eux; \
    \
    url="https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init"; \
    wget "$url"; \
    chmod +x rustup-init; \
    ./rustup-init -y --no-modify-path --default-toolchain stable; \
    rm rustup-init; \
    chmod -R a+w $RUSTUP_HOME $CARGO_HOME;

ENV PATH /usr/local/cargo/bin:$PATH
```

The image gets built fine, but when I run the image with
`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 dockerimage` I am not able to access `cargo` the Rust package manager within the terminal of RStudio Server.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: As I told you when you asked in the GH issue ticket, I would install the rust toolchain via `apt-get`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Unfortunately I am not able to install `cargo` in `rocker/tidyverse`. Looks like its not in the `debian:stretch` archive.

Comment: What makes you think our containers use Debian stable? They do not; and that is plainly document. And testing and unstable [have cargo as seen here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cargo).

Comment: At least -- "my" containers do. Carl may use a mix, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a tidyverse variant starting from testing too.  Choose your starting container carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log into the  running container using

```
$ docker exec -it <container-name>  bash
```

you will find something like this:

```
root@58906b77cc2f:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@58906b77cc2f:/# which cargo
/usr/local/cargo/bin/cargo
root@58906b77cc2f:/# cargo
Rust's package manager

USAGE:
    cargo [OPTIONS] [SUBCOMMAND]
[...]
```

However, the RStudio Server is executed as user `rstudio`, and there the situation is different:

```
root@58906b77cc2f:/# su - rstudio
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ cargo
sh: 2: cargo: not found
```

So either install Rust into a location that is part of the default `PATH`, e.g. using `apt` as suggested by Dirk in the comments. Or make setting `PATH`, `RUSTUP_HOME` and `CARGO_HOME` applicable to other users, e.g. by adding it to `/etc/profile`.

Comment: This is all well and good, but clearly it should be `... exec -it ...` — it just reads better ;-).

Comment: @Shepmaster here you go :-)

Comment: @RalfStubner For your first option, I tried using `apt-get` but `cargo` was not available for the base image `rocker/tidyverse`. So I opted for your second option and this is the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/rust-rstudio/) I built. But when I try to run `cargo`, it throws `error: no default toolchain configured`.

Comment: @SumanKhanal You also have to set `RUSTUP_HOME` and `CARGO_HOME` for the rstudio user.

Comment: @RalfStubner I am not able to do that. Can you give more tips ?

Comment: @SumanKhanal Just add `export RUSTUP_HOME=/usr/local/rustup` and `export CARGO_HOME=/usr/local/cargo` at the end of the `profile` file you are including in your docker image.

Comment: @RalfStubner Finally did it with your help. Many thanks.

Comment: @SumanKhanal You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer.